# Web API 2 Custom Attribute Route (Slash Version) not working but Querystring Version does

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api2

So I have a Web API 2 project with, currently, 2 controller actions - each representing a 'get' API request.

I have a route prefix of:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
```

One of the APIs has a custom route as follows:

```
[Route("get/address/UK/{locatorID:int?}")]
public AddressDetails GetAddressDetails(int locatorID)
{
```

It works just fine using either:

```
http://localhost:56135/api/v1/get/address/UK/1
```

OR

```
http://localhost:56135/api/v1/get/address/UK/?LocatorID=1
```

The other has a custom route as below:

```
[Route("suggest/addresses/UK/{howMany:int?}/{useBoundary:int?}/{boundarySize?}/{useBias:int?}/{query?}/{latitude?}/{longitude?}")]
        public List<SuggestedAddressesSimple> GetFriendlyAddresses(int howMany = 20, int useBoundary = 0, int boundarySize = 100, int useBias = 0, string query = "", string latitude = "0", string longitude = "0")
        {
```

The following call does not work:

```
http://localhost:56135/api/v1/suggest/addresses/UK/24/1/5/1/men/51.308111600/-0.7798636999
```

But this version does:

```
http://localhost:56135/api/v1/suggest/addresses/UK/24/1/5/1/?query=men&latitude=51.308111600&Longitude=-0.7798636999
```

So, yeah, it works with a querystring approach but I'd ideally like it to work with both. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

### Edit

In fact I can get this to work correctly for all but the last 'Longitude' attribute.

This works:

```
http://localhost:56135/api/v1/suggest/addresses/UK/24/1/5/1/men/51.308111600/?Longitude=0.7798636999
```

but this does not:

```
http://localhost:56135/api/v1/suggest/addresses/UK/24/1/5/1/men/51.308111600/-0.7798636999
```

### Edit 2

I thought it was perhaps an issue using a string value for a decimal but even changing the type to decimal does not solve this problem.

```
[Route("suggest/addresses/UK/{howMany:int?}/{useBoundary:int?}/{boundarySize:int?}/{useBias:int?}/{query?}/{latitude:decimal?}/{longitude:decimal?}")]
        public List<SuggestedAddressesSimple> GetFriendlyAddresses(int howMany = 20, int useBoundary = 0, int boundarySize = 100, int useBias = 0, string query = "", decimal latitude = 0, decimal longitude = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, the only way I got the above to work was to add a final slash:

```
http://localhost:56135/api/v1/suggest/addresses/UK/24/1/5/1/men/51.308111600/-0.7798636999/
```

I'm not sure why I had to do this though...

### UPDATE - Why this was happening

I have since been explained that the issue is to do with the dot/period within the latitude and longitude points. IIS believes it to be a file extension.

A suggestion was to make the modules section of your web.config say

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

but I found [this blog post](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) which suggested that was an unnecessary waste of resources and proposed a less resource intensive approach.